# При копирование из textarea в div с помощью JS не копируются переносы.

Tags: html, textarea, javascript

При копирование из textarea в div с помощью JS не копируются переносы т.е. они обрабатываются как пробелы.

Код:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function doit()
{
document.getElementById('comment_text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('comment').value;

}

</script>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="comment_text"></div>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="45" name="comment" id="comment">test</textarea>        
        <input type="button" value="Печать" onClick="doit();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это естественное поведение html.

```
document.getElementById('comment_text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('comment').value.replace(/(\n|\r)+/g, '<br>');
```

Либо пропишите в стилях `#comment_text{white-space:pre}`.